# Tkinter StringVar error

Tags: python, string, tkinter, converters, tk-toolkit

Hi i get an error with this code that StringVar() is not defined, and its probably a small thing but i am not that experienced with tkinter and would like some help, thanks.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Converter1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.variable = StringVar()
        self.variable.set("Miles to Kilometers") # default dropdown menu value
        self.menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, variable, "Miles to Kilometers", "Kilometers to Miles")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Convert!", command=self.convertMK)
        self.button.pack()
        self.menu.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def convtertMK(self): # converts the miles and kilometers using the dropdown menu
        if var.get() == "Miles to Kilometers":
            print(int(self.entry.get()) * 1.6093)
        else:
            print(int(self.entry.get()) / 1.6093)        



converter = Converter1()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MaxBookPro/Desktop/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    converter = Converter1()
  File "/Users/MaxBookPro/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.variable = Variable1
NameError: global name 'Variable1' is not defined
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the `tk.StringVar()`, as you did for every other tk function you specified.

```
self.variable = tk.StringVar()
```

This is because you just did an `import tk`. As an alternative, you could import just the functions you need, or even all of them, by one of the two following lines:

```
from tk import StringVar
from tk import *
```